# Using array_map instead of foreach in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$inventory = [
    'Apples' => ['Golden Delicious', 'Granny Smith','Fuji'],
    'Oranges' => ['Valencia', 'Navel', 'Jaffa']
];
```

What I would like to end up with is an array with the following:

```
['Apples','Oranges']
```

I can do:

```
$fruits = [];
foreach ($inventory as $key => $value) {
    $fruits[] = $key;
}
```

I am trying to educate myself on the use array_map, I tried:

```
$fruits[] = array_map('fruitTypes', $inventory);

function fruitTypes($item) {
    echo key($item)."\n";
    echo array_key_first($item)."\n";
    echo $item[0]."\n";
    //return something that will give me 'Apples' followed by 'Oranges'
}
```

But I am getting this:

```
0
0
Golden Delicious
0
0
Valencia
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to use `array_keys` in conjuction with array map. the keys in array map is not accessible out of the box

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), which returns an array of the keys of an associative array.

```
$fruits = array_keys( $inventory )
```

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to learn about array_map, the example I gave is a simple case. I am trying to figure out how to extract each key though a callback function.

Comment: You can't use `array_map` as it does not provide the keys on the parameter of the callback function so you might want to take a look at `array_walk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Array Keys would do this, not array Map.

```
<?php

inventory = [
    'Apples' => ['Golden Delicious', 'Granny Smith','Fuji'],
    'Oranges' => ['Valencia', 'Navel', 'Jaffa']
];

$keys = array_keys( $inventory );

var_dump($keys);
```

Would produce:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Apples"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Oranges"
}
```